# Using navigation bar on tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, swift2, xcode7

I am new in xcode. I use xcode 7.

I am trying to add a navigation bar on tab bar controller.

[image]

in that screenshot, i selected top translucent bar black but it doesn't appear when i run the project

My main purpose is to show a top bar and add an image (logo) on it.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: have you tried to embed it in a navigation controller?

Comment: how to do that, can you please explain ?

Comment: check my edited Answer @RULE101

Comment: @RULE101 select your view controller, then from 'Editor' -> `Embed in` -> `Navigation Controller`

Comment: @RULE101 check my answer please

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your format is not correct. please add Navigation Controller in your tab controller.

Select your `ViewController` and Click Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller

like this :

[image]

Add navigation controller like this :

[image]

I hope its work for you.

Add image to your navigation bar :

```
var image = UIImage(named: "abc.jpg") as UIImage
self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, 
                                                   forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks. One more question how to add an image to navigation bar ? Should i add a nagivation bar item ?

Comment: Ok i will, how can i add an image to navigation bar ?

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, 
                                                   forBarMetrics: .Default)  it will work for me @RULE101

Comment: ok it works but i need change image size and position, any way to do that ?

Comment: You have to apply the image as per the size of navigation bar that's it. Like as 640x64 size of iPhone 5s. @RULE101

Comment: Yes, but my question about images correctly answered by him.

Answer (score 2):

To add navigation controller:

select your view controller, then from 'Editor' -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller

To add image to your navigation bar, do this in your view did load :

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "yourimage.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

To change the image size, you would need to change the imageView size as the folowoing

```
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 150, 150, 150)); // set as you want
    imageView.image = logo;
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Comment: So close, how to change image size and position properties ?

Comment: @RULE101 it would be better if you can select an image with the correct size

Answer (score 0):

You shoul’d manually add navigation bar into your project and set it up manually. Or better is to add Navigation controller